# Powershell - Efficient way to keep content and append to the same file?

Tags: powershell

I want to keep the first comment section lines of a file and overwrite everything else. Currently this section is 27 lines long.

Each line begins with a # (think of it as a giant comment section).

What I want to do is keep the initial comment section, delete everything following the comment section, then append a new string to this file just below this comment section.

I found a way to hardcode it, but I think this is pretty ineffecient. I don't think it's best to hardcode in 27 as a literal.

The way I've handled it is:

```
$fileProc = Get-Content $someFile
                   
$keep = $fileProc[0..27]

$keep | Set-Content $someFile
                   
Add-Content $someFile "`n`n# Insert new string here"
Add-Content $someFile "`n EMPTY_PROCESS.EXE"
```

Is there a more efficient way to handle this?

Comment: So it isn't always 27 lines? You want to take all lines from the start that start with `#`? Can the `#` be preceded by whitespace? Can there be empty lines between `#` lines? Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: @mklement0 It's currently 27 lines, but the comment section might add more comments to it. 

Every single line in this section begins with a # and I only want to keep this section and overwrite the rest of the file. The first new line proceeding the comment section is a blank line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`switch` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) to efficiently extract the section of comment lines at the start.

```bash
Set-Content out.txt -Value $(
  @(
    switch -Wildcard -File $someFile {
      '#*' { $_ }
      default { break } # End of comments section reached.
    }
  ) + "`n`n# Insert new string here", "`n EMPTY_PROCESS.EXE"
)
```

Note:

- To be safe, the above writes to a *new* file, `out.txt`, but you can write directly back to `$someFile`, if desired.
- [Wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) expression `#*` assumes that each line in the comment section starts with `#`, with no preceding whitespace; if you need to account for preceding whitespace, use the `-Regex` switch in lieu of `-Wildcard`, and use [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) `'^\s*#'` in lieu of `'#*'`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about limiting it to first set of 27 or so lines but this should work.

First line below is to only keep the lines of file that start with '#'.

```
(Get-Content $somefile) | Where { $_ -match "^#" } | Set-Content $somefile

Add-Content $somefile "`n`nblah blah"
Add-Content $somefile "`nglug glug blug glug"
```

You can then use Add-Content for additional lines. *Hope this helps :]*

Comment: Promising, but if you want to write back to the same file you're reading from in a single pipeline, you must enclose the `Get-Content` call in `(...)` to ensure that the file is read in full into memory first. Also, your solution would at least hypothetically also include _later_ `#`-prefixed lines, after the initial block.

Comment: Like this `(Get-Content)`, Ohh ok noted.
Yes, it doesn't stop with first block, and picks every `#`-prefixed line ^^'. Not sure how to.

Comment: @mklement0 is correct. This would include later #-prefixed lines, which is something I am trying to avoid. 

I only want the initial comment block. I will include a picture of the file and what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> Efficient way [...] pretty inefficient [...] a more efficient way

- Don't open the file many times, paying the cost of ACL security and AntiVirus checks and disk access delays.
- Avoid PowerShell cmdlets and scriptblocks.
- Avoid loops in PowerShell, push work to lower layers.
- Avoid heavyweight searches like regex and wildcard.
- Avoid making arrays of string for the lines.

Open file once, do a single linear scan and truncate when the pattern is found  then write new data. Assuming no other comment lines in the data the pattern is "the last "\n#" is the start of the last comment, then the newline after that is the cutoff". e.g.:

```
$f = [System.IO.FileStream]::new('d:\test.txt', 'open')

$content = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($f).ReadToEnd()

$lastComment = $content.LastIndexOf("`n#")
$nextLine    = $content.IndexOf("`n", 1+$lastComment)
$f.SetLength($nextLine) # truncate

$w = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($f)
$w.WriteLine("new next Line")
$w.Close()
```

If there could be other comment lines, redesign the file so there is a sentinal value to find - easier than finding the absence of a thing.

Compared to mklement0's answer this doesn't cost any PowerShell cmdlet startup time, uses no subshells, no wildcard pattern matching, no arrays of string, and doesn't open the file twice. On a file with 10,000 comment lines:

- your original code takes ~0.4 seconds
- mklement0's code takes ~0.04 seconds
- this code takes ~0.02 seconds.

A more efficient way - QED.